# How to cancel conflicting / old tasks in Celery?

Tags: python, locking, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) + RabbitMQ.
When a Celery worker isn't available all the tasks are waiting in RabbitMQ.
Just as it becomes online all this bunch of tasks is executed immediately.
Can I somehow prevent it happening?

For example there are 100 tasks (the same) waiting for a Celery worker, can I execute only 1 of them when a Celery worker comes online?

Answer (score 2):

Since all the tasks are the same in your queue, A better way to do this is to **send the task only once**, to do this you need to be able to track that the task was published, for example:

- **Using a lock**, example: [Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time)
- **Using a custom task ID and a custom state** after the task is published, for example:

To add a custom state when the task is published:

```
from celery import current_app
from celery.signals import after_task_publish

@after_task_publish.connect
def add_sent_state(sender=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    """Track Published Tasks."""
    # get the task instance from its name
    task = current_app.tasks.get(sender)

    # if there is no task.backend fallback to app.backend
    backend = task.backend if task else current_app.backend

    # store the task state
    backend.store_result(body['id'], None, 'SENT')
```

When you want to send the task you can check if the task has already been published, and since we're using a custom state  the task's state won't be `PENDING` when it's published (which could be unkown) so we can check using:

```
from celery import states

# the task has a custom ID
task = task_func.AsyncResult('CUSTOM_ID')

if task.state != states.PENDING:
    # the task already exists
else:
    # send the task
    task_func.apply_async(args, kwargs, task_id='CUSTOM_ID')
```

I'm using this approach in my app and it's working great, my tasks could be sent multiple times and they are identified by their IDs so this way each task is sent once.

If you're still want to cancel all the tasks in the queue you can use:

```
# import your Celery instance
from project.celery import app

app.control.purge()
```

Check the Celery FAQ [How do I purge all waiting tasks ?](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-purge-all-waiting-tasks)

Comment: I think your 'check for lock' code (2nd excerpt) has a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) - two processes executing this code at exactly the same time could both see there is no existing task with the ``CUSTOM_ID`` and both submit a task.  The use of signals is interesting, but you need an atomic "get lock" operation (analogous to [test-and-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set)) e.g. inserting a row into a task-lock table that has a unique index on the lock ID (like ``CUSTOM_ID`` here).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

First, Run only one worker with a concurrency of one.

```
celery worker -A your_app -l info -c 1
```

This command starts a worker with a concurrency of one. So only one task will be executed at a time. This is the preferred way to do it.

Second method is bit complicated. You need to acquire lock and release the lock to make sure only [one task is executed at a time](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time).

Alternatively, if you want, you can remove all the tasks from queue using `purge` command.

```
celery -A your_app purge
```

Comment: He also needs to set `CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER` to 1 because it's multiplied by the concurrency and the default is 4.

Comment: @Peter The default concurrency is equal to number of cpu cores. Also the worker will execute only one task irrespective of the number of messages fetched as concurrency is set to 1. http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Yes but the worker will prefetch 4 messages and execute 1 at a time, so in his case where he has the same task a 100 times in the queue it will be executed 4 times, so the worker needs to prefetch only 1 task and then purge all the tasks in the queue.